# Correct value for MAGICK_MAP_LIMIT and MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT

Tags: imagemagick, aws-lambda

The AWS Lambda function has 2 GB of RAM and 512 MB of hard disk space. I have set accordingly the environment variables

```
MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH   /tmp
MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT       512MB
MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT     1536MB
```

Which value should I choose for the environment variable MAGICK_MAP_LIMIT? From the documentation (https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#environment):

> Set maximum amount of memory map in bytes to allocate for the pixel
>   cache. When this limit is exceeded, the image pixels are cached to
>   disk (see MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT).

Based on the file system limit so 512 MB?

And what value is recommended for MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT?

Comment: For AWS's Lambda service, I would **not** set `MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT` or `MAGICK_MAP_LIMIT`, and let the defaults manage available resources. By nature/design, Lambda functions are isolated sandboxed containers, so I can't think of a benefit from reducing I/O thresholds.

Comment: Thanks @emcconville but if you do not set these environment variables you get the default ones which are

File: 3072

Area: 7.8963GB

Memory: 3.677GiB

Map: 7.354GiB

Disk: unlimited

and this ends up later in "Stream yields empty buffer"

Comment: @user1791139 are you cleaning up after yourself in the Lambda environment?  If you leave files in `/tmp` after the function runs, they will start to pile up as containers are reused -- the temp space is not automatically cleared... and if you are experiencing issues "later," this is a likely cause.